# Adding an extra domain to match target keywords

Tags: domains, 301-redirect

We have an existing brand and now a 'new entertainment' product, but the kewords and top results for this 'new entertainment' are dominated by the competition.

Is it a good idea to add an extra domain exactly matching these keywords, and point it our main domain?

eg. **www.NewEntertainment-City.com** 301 redirect to **www.ourBrand.com**

The goal is to attract more people looking for this 'new entertainment' in our city, but who are not familiar with our brand.

What would be the best scenario?

- 301 redirect
- domain alias
- a separate, small info page with links

Comment: Adding a domain name does nothing for you. Unless you are transferring your content over to the new domain, you will get absolutely nothing from your efforts. I do not ever recommend changing domain names. The disruption and loss of search potential makes it a lose lose scenario. As well, your example domain, will not offer anything you cannot compensate for withing content. You are targeting search terms that will not yield much. Search is not about keywords. It is about language. It is better to make your current site perform as it should and be done with it.

Comment: Adding an extra expired domain in the same industry with a backlink history would help definitely, but not a new one

Answer (score 1):

The idea isn't bad, but you must know that  a domain won't give you a high position on Google by itself - these times are over :(

Next you should acquire links to your site on other sites with the link text "new entertainment". The most important thing is that the links must be placed on normal sites (not some directories with viagra and other mess) with relatively similar content (to your "new entertainment").

Comment: thanks ... I start consider making a real portal with strong links to my page.